# AWS Javascript SDK -IncompleteSignatureException

Tags: aws-sdk-js

```
const Polly = new AWS.Polly({
  accessKeyId: 'part1/part2',
  secretAccessKey: 'KEY',
  region: 'eu-central-1',
});

Polly.describeVoices(...)
```

And result is

> IncompleteSignatureException: Credential must have exactly 5 slash-delimited elements

I count 6 slash-delimited elements, but my accessKeyId includes slash key.

How I can check my key or problem in another place?

Answer (score 0):

I jumble key with id, after change them up -- all works